# pam_tty audit logs gives too much of not required information

Tags: pam, selinux, auditd

We are using `pam_tty` to record all the commands that user types. We are interested in monitoring the user commands.

In the `audit.log`, when we grep for `USER_TTY`, there is too much of logging that comes.

Here is the attached log screenshoot :-

[image]

In the `data=` section, there should ideally be the command names, but most of the logs are full of some number like `6364202F...`.

The `aureport --tty` seems to be giving proper results with commands, but as we are sending the `audit.log` file to centralized log server, it becomes difficult to search for only commands entered by a specific user.

Comment: The data is in hex. Just decode it.

Answer (score 1):

I would run `ausearch -i` and then send the output of that back to your centralized log server. It not only decodes the HEX strings (there because there are spaces in the command typed by the user), but it will also interpret the `auid` (and others) into the appropiate `LNAME` it belongs to.

You could make use of ausearch's checkpoint ability to only send 'new' events to your store.